# Same font renders differently across two Mac both running the same OS version and browser version

Tags: html, css, rendering, font-face

The site I’m working on has a custom script link font, [Santa fe](http://www.identifont.com/similar?3HB) to be exact. On my Mac it renders in Firefox 5 as such:

[how it should render http://z17.me/oa2c+](http://z17.me/oa2c+)

This is how I want it to render.

On my client’s mac and a someone else’s Mac it renders (improperly) like:

[improper rendering http://idzr.org/5ume](http://idzr.org/5ume)

I was having the same problem before in Safari, but `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` fixed it; however, it appears tat there is no equivalent of that for Firefox.

I also have `text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;` on and generated the web font package using [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/).

Any ideas?

Edit: The font has this CSS applied to it:

```
font-family: SantaFeLetPlainRegular;
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
font-size: 21px;
text-transform: lowercase;
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
/* @doubtful_existance: I don’t think these even exist? Can’t hurt much, I guess. */
-moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-o-font-smoothing: antialiased;
/* end @doubtful_existance */
font-smoothing: antialiased;
text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(256, 256, 256, 0.01); /* A trick I’ve heard of to fix issues like this. */
opacity: 0.99; /* Another trick I’ve heard of to fix issues like this. */
```

Comment: Have you looked at the *exact* browser version (e.g. 5.0 vs 5.0.1)? 'cos it's the only thing I can think of. But in general HTML and CSS are not meant for achieving exact pixel-perfect results. Different clients *will* render your page slightly differently, and you have to just trust them to do it in a way that is close enough to what you want.

Comment: hello zyber, have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try applying a 0px text shadow with a similar color to your background:

`text-shadow: #fff 0 0 0;`

Also, did you try applying a `font-weight:normal;` directly to whatever element is using the script font? Sometimes Firefox can cascade a `bold` on you without you noticing.

Comment: Updated the original post, it should be more clear what CSS is being applies to it now.